# Google Analytics - Aggregate Pageviews on a URL Substring?

Tags: google-analytics, report

I want to aggregate page views in Google Analytics based on a sub string of the URL, but can't see a way. Details as follows

We have a bulletin that is published from our site every 14 days. The URL for each bulletin page finishes finishes with "/[bulletin_id]". As a simplified example, say there were three pages in bulletin 9 and four pages in bulletin 10, then the URLs might look like this:

```
/abc/9
/def/9
/ghi/9
/jkl/10
/mno/10
/pqr/10
/stu/10
```

We would like to see the data agregated like so:

Bulletin 9: 927 Pageviews
Bulletin 10: 1202 Pageviews

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Cheers

Brett Sh

Comment: Can you show what you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in facility to aggregate Pageviews via the interface (you can get at the numbers with some regex trickery, but this won't give you a nice report) and as a reporting question this would be off-topic anyway.

If you are happy with a solution that requires a bit of code (and works only for future data) you could create and send a hit scoped custom dimension that holds the bulletin name. (The mechanics of creating custom dimensions are [explained rather well in documentation](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2709828?)).

Hit scoped means it is send along with your pageview call (because you want the dimension to be attached to the pageview). As a value you pass the bulletin id (must be unique to the bulletin).

Then on all the different urls for bulletin 9 you send along the identifier for the bulletin as custom dimension (same for bulletin 10,11,n) and then create a custom report that shows the custom dimension as primary dimensions and the number of pageviews/hits as metric.

If you want to work with existing data you'd have to use an external tool (e.g. a Google Spreadsheet with some Apps script)